# What are the relations between geometric multiplicity and algebraic multiplicity, concerning diagonalizability?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that gemu <= almu and that if the sum of the gemu of all eigenvalues is equivalent to the dimension of the vector space, then the linear transformation is diagonalizable, but is there any direct connections between gemu, almu, and diagonalizability?

Comment: The linear transformation is diagonalizable if and only if the geometric multiplicity of *each* eigenvalue is equal to its algebraic multiplicity.  (This follows from what you actually said.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Wait, why do you need each eigenvalue's geometric multiplicy equal to algebraic multiplicity for the matrix to be diagnolizable?

Comment: If not, how will they all add up to the dimension of your vector space?

Comment: @TedShifrin I mean, I guess I'm just not getting the relevance of algebraic multiplicity to diagonalizability.

Answer (score 0):

For an $n\times n$ matrix $M$ to be diagonalizable, we need $n$ linearly independent eigen vectors.

If each eigen value gives us as many  eigenvectors as its algebraic multiplicity, we are done, otherwise we are not able to diagonalize our matrix.